# Can I disable the automatic keyboard pop-up of the SearchDelegate Class?

Tags: flutter, dart, focus, flutter-animation, text-editor

Im using the SearchDelegate Flutter class. It automatically opens the keyboard when I use the showSearch Method.

I figured that I could close it right away within one of the overwritten Methods. But I don't want it to pop-up in the first place. Only when taping the search bar.

I know that the SearchDelegate class has a _focusNode attribute but I don't know how to work with it.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be more helpful if you share the relevant codes.

Answer (score 0):

As of today *(december 2022)*, going strictly by your question : **no, you can't**.

Dart fields with a leading underscore `_` are not just a naming convention, they allow to mark fields as private. Such fields will only be available to :

- The declaring `.dart` file, when declared at top-level.
- The parent Dart object, when declared at scope-level.

Thus, your code does not have access to the `_focusNode` field, nor the `_SearchPageRoute<T>`, `_SearchPage<T>` or `_SearchPageState<T>` classes.

In conclusion, you can either deal with this limitation or create your own custom implementation of this search page. You could either build it from scratch, or by forking the existing `showSearch` implementation and modifying it to fit your needs.